# Destiny: The Taken King Problem With Xur

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

Alright guys, multi-part question here.

I'm playing the Destiny Legendary Edition on Xbox 360, Hunter Class. (level 40 ,of course)

So, every half-decent Destiny player knows that Xur, the Agent of the Nine, shows up in the tower every Friday Morning, and sells exotics, three of coins, etc, and then leaves Sunday morning.

As I understand it, he sells an exotic armor piece for each class, and then an exotic engram, and a legacy engram. He also sells either an exotic weapon OR an exotic weapon engram, as well as some other stuff.

My problem is this: for the past few weeks (three or four to be specific), he has sold neither an exotic weapon engram nor an exotic weapon. **I understand the bug with the Gjallerhorn and empty slot, but I know for a fact that he hasn't (tried to) sell it for three of four straight weeks.**

This week, he is supposed to be selling the Icebreaker, an exotic sniper rifle, according to all the websites that track him, and a lot of players say so too. However, he is not selling it for me, nor is he selling an exotic weapon engram. Like I said, the last few weeks, he hasn't sold any exotic weapons or weapon engrams except the SUROS Regime once. I checked my iPhone Destiny companion app, and it doesn't show that he's selling any exotic weapons or weapon engrams either. This is in disagreement with the websites that track him, one of which I'm pretty sure isn't wrong because it (claims) to read what he's selling for the Destiny API or something like that.

Any idea what's wrong?

Also, does it seem like he's repeating items a lot? He's sold the Skyyburner's Annex(hunter), Silver-Plated Ahamkara Grasps(hunter), and Claws of Ahamkara grips (warlock) a lot recently (multiple times each), it seems like he's repeating them a lot.

Does anyone know if any of these are acknowledged or unacknowledged bugs? Is it the fact that I'm playing on Xbox 360? What's wrong? Is anyone else having the same problem(comment if you are for this one don't answer)? Is it just me? Is there a fix or something that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

**AGAIN, this is not the bug that involves the Gjallerhorn being removed from his inventory**

Comment: what sites are you getting this information from?  There was a guy who was data mining and predicting Xur's inventory roughly a year ago, but I believe the access has since been patched.  Anything else is speculation, Bungie does not knowingly make this information available.  The reason I ask, Icebreaker was a Y1 exotic, and has not been upgraded to Y2, AFAIK.  Xur would most likely not sell an out of date exotic, so I speculate that you are looking at information for Xur's inventory from 2015.

Comment: Also, if you look at recent history, it seems that Xur sells: 1 exotic armor per class and some combo of two of the following: legacy exotic weapon engram, exotic weapon, exotic armor engram, exotic weapon engram. [Source](http://www.destinylfg.com/findxur/)

Comment: @turbo no a ton of the where is xur today sites said that today feb 19 2016 he's selling it

Comment: can you provide an example? I cannot find one.  In-game, bungie.net and the bungie app are the only guaranteed  and reliable sources for what Xur is selling.  Any site that claims to know what Xur is selling before he appears is purely speculation.  There is no bug, so don't worry you aren't missing out on anything.

Comment: @turbo sorry if I was unclear they say where he is today(he's here its Friday) and what he is selling today. They say that he is selling it but he's not

Comment: @turbo do you know why he stopped selling exotic weapons and weapon 'ngrams?

Comment: Yes, like the link I provided above: http://www.destinylfg.com/findxur/. He is not selling icebreaker this week.  My guess is that his inventory is randomly generated, and it's just been luck of the draw that he's sold no weapons or engrams.  If you can't provide a site that claims otherwise, I don't think this is valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're getting incorrect information from the websites you visit.  Once upon a time, I believe Xur had a more predictable schedule of wares, but recently it's only safe to assume that you'll probably see one armor item per class, some number of engrams, and then the consumables Three of Coins, Glass Needle, and Heavy Ammo Synth.

Reddit's [/r/destinythegame](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/) is generally your best source of Xur news, including where he is and what he is selling, along with a lot of comments about what of his inventory is worth getting excited about.  Look for a "Xur Megathread" near the top of the queue on Friday mornings.  [This is this week's thread, for instance.](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/46jr5i/xur_megathread_20160219/)

I wouldn't trust any site that disagrees with /r/destinythegame on a regular basis, since they tend to be pretty quick to post and quick to fix incorrect data compared to other sites out there.

Comment: Another option is to go to the [Vendors](https://www.bungie.net/en/Vendors/1/4611686018429587879/2305843009217525651?vendor=0&category=0) section of the Bungie website, and it will show Xûr's inventory (assuming he is around).

Comment: To be specific, Xur will always have one exotic armor piece per class, one year 2 weapon or random exotic engram in the fourth slot, and one random exotic legacy engram, along with the consumables.